# Insert Query issues in mysql while submitting through ajax Json format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am developing one website where i insert data through ajax in Json format to php page then after decoding it send to  mysql database,but if my string contains `<  >  || & ' "` characters then my web page gives php error.so how should i proceed further. It doesn't allow for inserting some  special characters ..

```
 var obj = {"comment": commentText, "postID": postID};
                var commentData = 'commentData=' + JSON.stringify(obj);


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: addNewCommentsUrl,
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: commentData,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
//                 $(document.body).off('click','.postComment');

                    },
                    success: function(result) {

                        commentBox.val("");
                        commentHolder.append(result);
//                     jQuery("#all-posts").masonry('reloadItems');
                        jQuery('#all-posts').masonry('layout');

                        var count = parseInt(parent.find("#commentContainer").text());
                        parent.find("#commentContainer").html(++count);

//                    $(document.body).on('click','.postComment');
                    }

                });// end of ajax
```

at php side

```
 $recievedData = $_POST['commentData'];
            $recieveddatajson = json_decode($recievedData);
            $lastCommentID = $recieveddatajson->{'commentID'};
            $parentPostID = $recieveddatajson->{'postID'};
```

Comment: Start for *reading* the error

Comment: what is the error? and can you show your code?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes It gives normal error i.e cannot insert null value to column.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes actually problem arise when encode and decode through json format  when string contains above special characters

Comment: Can you show us a sample data source being posted via ajax and the code for making the ajax request and the php post handler php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I see what you are doing. You don't need to do that. Here's a cut down version of your problem, showing you how to achieve ajax post:

**test.php**

```
<?php

// Handle Post
if (count($_POST))
{
    echo "You posted\r\n";
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: { "comment": "hello world", "postID": 1234 },
        // data: { "comment": commentText, "postID": postID },
        success: function(result) {
            alert("Server Said:\r\n" + result);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Outputs:

[image]

---

So when the request occurs, `data` fields and their values are available in php like this:

```
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : '';
$postID = isset($_POST['postID']) ? $_POST['postID'] : '';
```

Hope this helps.